# Как сохранить очередь в mobx-state-tree, при использовании flow

Tags: javascript, redux, mobx, flow

Делается запрос в flow(), и сразу же после него еще один, первый запрос исполняется быстрее, и отображаются невалидные данные, что с этим можно сделать?